# Google Apps Script for spotting the differences between two columns of a google sheet, ignoring blank cells and multiple instances

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script

I'm a newbie JavaScipt developer and I need some help in the following situation:

I have two columns of data ("COLUMN A" and "COLUMN B") in Google Sheets, where each cell contains product names, but "COLUMN B" also contains blank cells (which I'd like to skip when searching and matching), and it looks like this:

#### "COLUMN A"         "COLUMN B"

```
 Product1        Product89
 Product2        Product1 
 Product3        Product20
 Product4
 Product5        Product4
 Product6        
 Product7        Product6
 Product8        Product89
 PRoduct9
 Product10       Product15
 Product11       Product89
```

**PROBLEM:** I want to create a ***search*** and ***match*** function which works for these two columns, and spots the products from "COLUMN B" **which are NOT** in "COLUMN A" and lists them in a third column, **without blank cells and only one instance of each product** (if there are more than one products with the same name in "COLUMN B" that are not in "COLUMN A").

**The result for the above example would be:**

#### "COLUMN C (RESULT)"

```
     Product89
     Product20
     Product15
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make a script for you prob.

I hope he can help you for your project.

```
        function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
    var myArrayA ;
    var myArrayB ;
    var myArrayC ;
    var control = false;
    var controlC = false;
    var indic = 0;
    var i;
    var a;

    var c;
      sheet.getRange("C:C").clear();
       myArrayA = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues(); 
       myArrayB = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues(); 
       myArrayC = sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();


      Logger.log(myArrayA[0][0]);

        for ( i = 0 ; i<= 10 ; i++)
        {

              for ( a = 0 ; a <= 10; a++)
                {

                    if (myArrayB[i][0] == myArrayA[a][0] && myArrayB[i][0] != "")


 {

                  control = true;        
                }           
            }

          if ( control == false )
          {





             for ( b=0; b <= 10 ; b++)
             {
               if ( myArrayC[b][0] == myArrayB[i][0] && myArrayC[b][0] != ""){
                 controlC = true;
               }

             }

             if ( controlC == false){

             myArrayC[indic][0] = myArrayB[i][0];
             indic = indic + 1;
             }


          }

          control = false;
          controlC = false;

    }




  sheet.getRange("D:D").setValues(myArrayC);
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea to answer these 'here is my spec, write it' questions

Comment: Thanks a lot Hann, your script gave a solution to my problem, although it does not skip blank cells, just like my script. Your solution is more efficient, and much more faster than mine.

Comment: If you can, please check the provided script again, because I can't find the problem where do empty cells register in myArrayC. The result column does contain empty cells too...

Comment: you can just build other Array.
Copy the result on a new Array without empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily without involving a script using built-in functions:

1. Use a `VLOOKUP` to search for instances of B:B in A:A:

```
=VLOOKUP(B:B,A:A,1,FALSE)
```

2. Strip out unwanted/non-results:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,A:A,1,FALSE)),B:B,)
```

3. Get `UNIQUE` results only and remove blanks by `SORT`ing the list:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,A:A,1,FALSE)),B:B,)),1,TRUE)
```